# Construction of a idempotent, self-conjugate linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In Peter McCullagh, Tensor Methods in Statistics the following is stated (my rewriting)

$$
P = X (X^T G X)^{-1} X^T G
$$

where $G$ is a Gram matrix, $X$'s columns are spanning vectors of a $R^p$ vector space.

$P$ should then be a idempotent and self-conjugate transformation, with $P X = X$ and $< P v, u>=< v, P u>$ for any vectors $v$ and $u$.

However testing this numerically with random vectors and matrices I cannot get to this result.

I'm using
$$
G = M^T M
$$
where $M$ is also a random matrix. I can confirm this only if I have $G=I$ the identity matrix.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding? Unfortunately McCullagh does not give or reference a proof.

Thanks

Comment: $PX=X$ is obvious. To check that $\langle Pv,u\rangle=\langle v,Pu\rangle$, simply use their characterization of $G$ w.r.t. the inner product: for any (column) vectors $x,y$, $$\langle x,y\rangle=x^TGy.$$ $\langle Pv,u\rangle=\langle v,Pu\rangle$ will then come by itself when writing.

Comment: Agree $P X = X$ is obvious, but
$$
\langle Pv,u\rangle = \left(Pv \right)^TGu = v^TGPu = \langle v,Pu\rangle
$$
does not really get me any further.

Comment: Check that $P^TG=GP$.

Comment: Hmm, yes confirmed. I guess I must have a bug in my implementation.
Thanks.
If you want you get attributed the answer I guess you need to, make an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$PX=X$ is obvious.

To prove that $$
\langle Pv,u\rangle=\langle v,Pu\rangle
,$$ i.e. that $$\left(Pv \right)^TGu = v^TGPu,$$ simply check that $P^TG=GP$.